# How to create itemview like Whatsapp message Itemview of recyclerview

Tags: java, android, kotlin, whatsapp

The chat itemview of recyclerview of whatsapp message screen is having different type of text view , please refer the screenshot below, and let me know how can I create one like that .

In the image you can see the margin between the message text and time textview , I cannot figure out that how it is changing the bottom margin when we try to send a message to overlap the time text .

[image: screenshot of whatsapp chat]